# Difference of similar, yet different java distroless images

Tags: docker, distroless

I have tried to find out in the different readmes and information sections available, but didn't find an answer, so also a possible trace to where I might be able to find this out would help a lot:

What is the difference between the different java 11 distroless images, and which one is the one that is supposed to be used? They all differ in creation date / amount of security patches inside:

- gcr.io/distroless/java:11
- gcr.io/distroless/java11-latest
- gcr.io/distroless/java11-debian11-latest

There was no article / readme / description available to see the intended / unintended differences in these containers.